# Equivalent of .html() for php function

Tags: javascript, php

`$('#target').html(data)` returns html for data in the the element with `id="target"`.
but what if i want to return a php function ?

Say there is a php function in data and i want to implement it in the `#target element; .html()` will not get the job done as it will only return the html ( it can return a string from echo but I want it the implement the hole function)

Is there an equivalent to `.html()`  but for php code?

Example:
page index.php, i have an ajax call:

```
$('#something').on('click', function() {    
var b = document.getElementById('anything').value;  
$.post('sort.php', {y: b}, function(data) {
    $('#target').html(data);
});
});
```

And my sort.php file looks like this:

```
function latest($n) {
$genre= $_POST['y'];
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "artlibr1_default", "azerty123", "artlibr1_01");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE genre='$genre' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT $n, 1";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 return $list['path'];
}
}
```

So they isn't any real html output, just a php function ...
So `$('#target').html(data)` will return nothing .

So my question is : How can i get my php function to be added to my index.php file throw this AJAX ? is there a function for this?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make any sense to me.  Can you elaborate with some sample code?  It sounds like you're confusing server-side and client-side code.

Comment: PHP is run *server* side, not *client* side.  You can't embed a PHP function call in JavaScript without using AJAX.

Comment: @David updated question with example

Comment: @Jackymamouth: Now it *really* doesn't make any sense.  If there's no output, then exactly *what* do you expect `.html()` to do with it?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @David i understand that they isn't any output and that .html() isn't going to be any use as they is no output.
I was just wondering if they was a similiar javascript function  like .html() but for php script

Comment: @Jackymamouth: Well, no, because JavaScript and PHP do very different things.  In your server-side code if you had HTML to display somewhere then you'd simply display it.  If it's a string variable, for example, then you might `echo` that string to the output.  Or if it's static literal content then you'd just put it where you want it in the PHP file.  There really isn't a *need* for this functionality in PHP, since it doesn't modify the HTML DOM after it's been loaded.

Comment: Okay, so there is two problem. First you're function gonna return only the first result, second you have to echo the result set to be able to return it with ajax.

Comment: I think you are slightly confusing some important stuff here. Javascript is a client-side language and AJAX belongs to it. PHP is a server side language and belongs to the server itself. PHP's role is to **return something** to the client, either plain text, HTML, json and so on. What you are calling AJAX is called an asyncronous request from the client (javascript in this case) to the server (php in this case) but, because php is a **different language** you CANNOT return a function (because javascript just CAN'T interprete php), but it may return something else (plain text, html.... json..).

Comment: @David uhm okey :/ ; "There really isn't a need for this functionality in PHP, since it doesn't modify the HTML DOM after it's been loaded" this is true but i have a particular situation where i have another AJAX for loading content when arriving at bottom of screen so i was guessing it might be able in that case to modify html dom . Any way very confused, going to look for another solution !! Thanks for the help =)

Comment: That said, if you just want the php function to be called, you can simply include the php file "sort.php" in your index.php and call that function inside the div. Being entirely honest, I didn't understand your problem yet, mostly because your question looks so confused that the best we can do is properly explain you that you cannot call a php function in javascript. That said, I think it's still important to prompt you about the fact that you should sanitize the post field "y" (in sort.php), because your query is really really easy to inject. Either use prepared statements or sanitize.

Comment: @Jackymamouth: `"where i have another AJAX for loading content"` - That implies that the AJAX call would, well, have *output* of some kind.  That it would return the content to be loaded.  In which case, in your JavaScript, you'd use something like `.html()` to show that output.  I don't know where the confusion is here, but it seems to be stemming from some fundamental misunderstandings you may have about how web development works.

Comment: @briosheje Yes very confused, i am sorry that i am not clear enough as to what i am trying to do :/ have been stuck all afternoon on this problem :/
However you have made it clear that what i was trying to do cannot be done =) and i understand why now .
I am going to sleep on this and try to fix the problem from a different angle tomorow , thanks for the guidance =)

Comment: (Side note: Your PHP code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.  You should probably look into using prepared statements with query parameters.)

Comment: @Jackymamouth : Technically it is not correct to say that what you are trying to accomplish is impossible: there are some tricky ways of calling a function through javascript but the "input" code (received from php) must be javascript. However, by seeing your code, I think that what you are trying to accomplish is just printing some data received through php. If you want to do that using AJAX, then implement a function and **echo** the result in your php script so that the response of your ajax request will be what is echoed in php and, through javascript, put it inside the div, that's it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the function in your PHP file, only declaring it.

After declaring latest($n), you need to run it. latest(0); or something.